How to zoom on chartview and click on scatter points in qml?
I want to be able to zoom in and out on the chart. For that I can use a MouseArea. But when using that I'm not able to click on scatter points anymore. How can I handle this?
Is there anyway to do zooming without using MouseArea?
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtCharts 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ChartView {
        id: chart
        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true
        legend.visible: false

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisX
            min: 0
            max: 10
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisY
            min: 0
            max: 10
        }

        ScatterSeries {
            id: scatterSeries
            name: "Scatter Data"
            axisX: axisX
            axisY: axisY
            Component.onCompleted: {
                scatterSeries.append(1, 1);
                scatterSeries.append(2, 2);
                scatterSeries.append(3, 3);
                scatterSeries.append(4, 4);
                scatterSeries.append(5, 5);
            }
            onClicked: {
                console.log("Clicked point:", point.x, point.y)
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: chart
            onWheel: wheelEvent => {
                const factor = wheelEvent.angleDelta.y > 0 ? 1.2 : 0.8;
                chart.zoom(factor);
            }
        }
    }
}


Have you thought of using different UI/UX action for zooming, e.g. Slider?

@StephenQuan Yes. but it's not user friendly. doing it with mouse wheel is better.

[EDIT] New answer, move MouseArea outside your ChartView, e.g.
MouseArea {
    ChartView {
    }
}

Original answer use WheelHandler instead of MouseArea:
            /*
            MouseArea {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: chart
                onWheel: wheelEvent => {
                    const factor = wheelEvent.angleDelta.y > 0 ? 1.2 : 0.8;
                    chart.zoom(factor);
                }
            }
            */

            WheelHandler {
                id: wheelHandler
                onWheel: wheelEvent => {
                    const factor = wheelEvent.angleDelta.y > 0 ? 1.2 : 0.8;
                    chart.zoom(factor);
                }
            }



didn't work. WheelHandler is not a type

I used Qt5.15 and WheelHandler is definitely there. If you're using a much older version of Qt, then, consider putting your ChartView inside the MouseArea, see edited answer.
